# Find out if an Objective-C class overrides a method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, introspection, objective-c-runtime

How can I find out, at runtime, if a class overrides a method of its superclass?

For example, I want to find out if a class has it's own implementation of `isEqual:` or `hash`, instead of relying on a super class.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you talking about looking up something in the documentation? Some sort of runtime check? What?

Comment: @rmaddy He is clearly asking about checking whether a subclass contains custom implementation of a method declared in its superclass. And the question also contains the objective-c runtime tag.

Comment: @DominikHadl Yes,that's exactly what I want. I want to do this in runtime. Assume I don't have documentation for the said class.

Comment: Though it is an interesstig question, I'd would consider it code smell if it was used in production code.

Comment: @vikingosegundo It's for unit testing code, not production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to get a list of the methods, and look for the one you want:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

BOOL hasMethod(Class cls, SEL sel) {
    unsigned int methodCount;
    Method *methods = class_copyMethodList(cls, &methodCount);

    BOOL result = NO;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < methodCount; ++i) {
        if (method_getName(methods[i]) == sel) {
            result = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    free(methods);
    return result;
}
```

`class_copyMethodList` only returns methods that are defined directly on the class in question, not superclasses, so that should be what you mean.

If you need class methods, then use `class_copyMethodList(object_getClass(cls), &count)`.