# To be a key of an NSDictionary, must a class also implement isEqual: and hash?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nscopying

I understand that a class must implement `NSCopying` in order to be a key of an `NSDictionary`, but is implementing `isEqual:` and `hash` also necessary or advisable?

If yes, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Why?

Consider accessing an element of a dictionary, how does `NSDictionary` find the object associated with a key? By *comparing* the key value you provide with the keys in the dictionary.

It is a rule when you implement `isEqual:` that you also implement `hash`, objects which compare equal must have the same hash. Consider further how the dictionary may organise the storage of the key/value pairs, it uses a hash-based storage structure.

HTH

**Addendum**

Seeing what I guess is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809308/find-out-if-an-objective-c-class-overrides-a-method) you've also asked I will qualify the the above "Yes":

If a class inherits `isEqual:` and `hash` methods which appropriately define equality for itself it need not override the methods with its own versions. In all probability this will **not** be true if the class directly inherits from `NSObject`.

Comment: Upvoting your answer was easier than finishing the similar answer I was typing.

Comment: @rmaddy - Thanks :-) And I'm so often the slow typist.

Comment: NSObject implements isEqual: by comparing pointers, and hash by taking the pointer as the hash value. So any two different objects will be considered different. That's often Ok. For example, two UIViews would only be considered equal if they are actually the same view.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html

> A key-value pair within a dictionary is called an entry. Each entry
>   consists of one object that represents the key and a second object
>   that is that key’s value. Within a dictionary, the keys are unique.
>   That is, no two keys in a single dictionary are equal (as determined
>   by isEqual:). In general, a key can be any object (provided that it
>   conforms to the NSCopying protocol—see below), but note that when
>   using key-value coding the key must be a string (see Key-Value Coding
>   Fundamentals). Neither a key nor a value can be nil; if you need to
>   represent a null value in a dictionary, you should use NSNull